# Performance dramatically slower on SqlDataReader vs SSMS

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have a performance problem on a query which is running in about 4 seconds in SQL Server Management Studio, vs about 80 seconds in c# when iterating through a SqlDataReader.

This query is pretty simple, it returns a single string column which contains on average about 230 characters of text for about 200,000 rows. It looks like this:
`SELECT TOP 200000 [t].[mytestcolumn] FROM [TestTable] AS [t]`

Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/performance/troubleshoot-application-slow-ssms-fast I ensured the following:

- the execution plans are exactly the same
- ARITHABORT was OFF originally but it didn't make a difference if I run `SET ARITHABORT ON;` in my c# command before the `SELECT`

In c# I run a `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()` and iterate through my results in the simplest way possible, like so:

```cs
while (reader.Read()) {
   reader.GetString(0);
}
```

Detailed profiling on SQL server confirmed that the queries are exactly the same and ran the same plan, but `duration` is about 40 times higher when running the c# code.

Additional info:

- The SQL server is located in a different physical location, but both my app and SSMS are running locally on my machine.
- I'm using classes from `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` which is available since I'm referencing nuget package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` v 3.1.23 in my app
- The web app is running on `net6.0`

What can explain such a difference? How can I retrieve the data in my application as fast as in SSMS? Is there a better alternative than iterating through a data reader?

Comment: I would argue that loading 200k records into memory at once is not a very good idea no matter how fast it would be. Personally I would look into batching approaches. One thing you can try is disabling change tracker (if you are not going to modify the data later).

Comment: Also not SSMS specialist but potentially it does not materialize the whole data. Also check the profiler - how long the actual query is executed.

Comment: Change tracking doesn't apply as I'm not loading any data in an EF context (just executing a datareader). Also in SSMS it does seem to materialize the data enough so that I can quickly scroll through it immediately after the query has executed (after about 5 seconds).
As per the duration in the profiler, as explained above it showed that DataReader execution took about 40 times longer.

Comment: @RyanWilson from OP _"The SQL server is located in a different physical location, but **both my app and SSMS are running locally on my machine.**"_

Comment: @JulienBrousseau Can you reduce the number of columns being returned since it appears you only need the first one in the table?

Comment: @RyanWilson I am only returning one column (the one I need)

Comment: The first thing is to find where SQL Server loose times. You can use SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats to see wait type of wait is long. First in SSMS and second with your app. This needs to identify your session by executing a whatever query with a tag like "SELECT 'abracadabra;' and get the session_id from SQL Profiler

Comment: Which version of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient there were perf improvements in the latest versions?

Comment: Can you remove Entity Framework as a test? You haven't mentioned how/where you are using it?

Comment: I have removed all references to to Entity Framework, and am down to only using components from `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` namespace. Interestingly if I double the `Packet Size` to 16,000 in the connection string (default is 8,000), the execution time is halved.

Answer (score 6):

I think I have found the issue, which was caused by having enabled Multiple Active Result Sets in my connection string.

Setting `MultipleActiveResultSets=False` immediately dropped the execution time to less than 4 seconds, which is much more in line with what I experience in SSMS.